# Why is Cygwin Python executed version different than included in $PATH variable?

Tags: cygwin, environment-variables, path

I have installed two version of Python 2 and 3 and installed cygwin, cygwin $PATH variable includes Python3 paths but when I looked version of python on cygwin console it shows as Python2, how can I resolve this?

I have tried restarting, including all libs of Python3 in $PATH and also my command prompt shows as Python3.

### Edit:

*Here is Python3 path:* **"C:\Users\hasany\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32"**

*Here is "echo $PATH" output:*
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:**/cygdrive/c/Users/hasany/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32:/cygdrive/c/Users/hasany/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Scripts:**/cygdrive/c/Users/hasany/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Lib:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/PuTTY:/cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/hasany/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/libs:/cygdrive/c/Users/hasany/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/DLLs:

Comment: please [edit] and include the output of `echo $PATH` and of `where python`

Comment: You can see there is no python2 paths. I think I have tried to reinstall after removing python2 from $PATH

Comment: cygwin has its own python 2 and 3. May be are you running it ?